# C++ socket writing too many characters

Tags: c++, sockets

This code is embedded in a "chat room" program using sockets.  It is reading from the client (myFD) and successfully appending a username to the front.
However, I have a problem writing extra characters in the write buffer.  What was sent last time is still stored and also sending.

For example, the first time I'd send (and write correctly)

> UN: Hello.

But on the second try, when I'd write, say, "NOT", the message sent would be:

> UN: NOTlo

The cout statement correctly "cout's" without the "lo" at the end, but the clients receive the "lo" at the end.  Am I overlooking something simple?

Code Below:

```
while ( (amount_read = read(myFD, buffer, 1024)) > 0)
{
    total = 0;
    strcpy(second, "");
    strcpy(second, username);
    total += unLength;
    strcat(second, ": ");
    total += 2;
    strcat(second, buffer);//, amount_read);
    total += amount_read;
    cout << second << endl;
    write(myFD, second, total);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you just need to tack a '\0' to the end of your current string ... btw cout is c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is not null terminated that's why you print old string. You can fix it adding `\0` at the end of string `buffer[amount_read]=0` or just clear whole string before next iteration.

To clear buffer you can use [`memset (buffer,'\0', 1024)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/). Maybe it's not fastest way but prevent storing rubbish or data that shouldn't be hosted longer than it's necessary.

Comment: Using memset doesn't have any effect.  I don't think it's with the string itself since cout works correctly.  Then again, I'm probably terribly misunderstanding how this all works.

Comment: Ah, no you got it - I strcat-ted a null character onto the end and solved everything just like I'd hoped.  Thank you!

Comment: np, it's quite common mistake (even for skilled progammers to forgot about `\0`). It's so frequently that tere is a joke about that: Two strings walk into a bar. One says "I'd like a beer please. 25s3z %- 9238435". The other string says "Sorry about my friend, he's not null-terminated."

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding in `'\0'` correctly.

I guess your transmit looks like this `write(myFD, buffer, strlen(buffer))`, then you will send everything but the 0 terminator. It works the first time because you probably did a `memset`.

`buffer[amount_read]=0;` will probably fix it.

Comment: Placed this at the beginning and end of function.  Doesn't seem to have any effect.